# Google Sheet Filter odd and even cells to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm building a weather station to track Growing Degree Days for when to apply plant growth regulator. it's all ready but am having on problem. I have a tab labeled "History" and need the odd number cells like A1,A3,A5,A7 to move that data to another tab called "High Low Temp Option". If that makes sense. for example I need A1 from "History" to move to K11 on "High Low Temp Option" tab. And just keep repeating like A3 to K12 and A5 to K13 and so on. Then I need to do the same thing to the evens so B2 to L11, B4 to L12 and so on. I'm not sure how to set up this equation for this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to try to write formulas when we can't see the spreadsheet, sheets (and names), data ranges, data types, layout, etc. and when we know neither your end goal or your field coming in. The most efficient and effective way to receive help will be if you can share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a spreadsheet that contains at least enough of a realistic representative sample to illustrate the problem and the result you want to see. As of right now, there's a lot that's unclear.

Comment: I hope you have already got your issue resolved ,  the project looks interesting, can you please share some details about this project with me if possible.

Comment: Sure! So I plan on using plant growth regulator (PGR) on my lawn and to know when you I need to reapply. To do that you need to calculate Growing Degree Days (GDD). and to get your GDD you need to use a local weather station because you need the High and the Low temp for the day to Calculate it. So I integrated a weather API to auto fill the high and low temp for the day. Its working now the only thing I want to do now is have it email me when the GDD threshold is at 200 so it emails me to reapply.

Answer (score 3):

in K11 put :

```
=indirect("Sheet1!A"&(row()-11)*2+1)
```

and drag downwards.

similarly, in L11 put :

```
=indirect("Sheet1!B"&(row()-11)*2+2)
```

and drag downwards.

That should do. (Sheet1 <-- chg to ur tab name)

Pls share if it works/not/understandable.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: glad it works. Once u get the logic u may apply it (row() +indirect() manipulation) elsewhere.. |  u may click on the 'tick' to mark this question as answered. ( :

Comment: @NathanGartner, [When someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: tq.. _/(^_^)/'' really wished [ans in comment can be accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) too

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is the script that copies the values from every second row from 'History' sheet to your first sheet into columns 'K' and 'L':

```
function copy_from_history_to_first_sheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sh_src = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  var data = sh_src.getDataRange().getValues().filter((_,i) => i%2 == 0);
  var col_A = data.map(x => [x[0]]);
  var col_B = data.map(x => [x[1]]);

  var sh_dest = ss.getSheetByName('High Low Temp Option');
  sh_dest.getRange('K11:K' + (col_A.length+10)).setValues(col_A);
  sh_dest.getRange('L11:L' + (col_B.length+10)).setValues(col_B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need A1 from "History" to move to K11 on "High Low Temp Option" tab. And just keep repeating like A3 to K12 and A5 to K13 and so on. Then I need to do the same thing to the evens so B2 to L11, B4 to L12 and so on.

I'll assume History is the tab name. You can do this cleanly with a filter too.

In K11:

```
=filter(History!A:A,mod(row(History!A:A),2)=1)
```

or

```
=filter(History!A:A,isodd(row(History!A:A)))
```

In L11:

```
=filter(History!B:B,mod(row(History!B:B),2)=0)
```

or

```
=filter(History!B:B,iseven(row(History!B:B)))
```